# How can I detect water or oil marks on the lens of my web camera using open-cv python?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ophym.png)My task is to detect the glare caused by oil strains or water on the lens of my web camera using open cv python. Can anyone suggest any method of doing it?

Comment: can you post a few example images so that we can get a feel for what you're seeing?

Comment: I attached an image above